# Using InstallShield, can I self-sign the installation package?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am creating an installer for a web application and using InstallShield Limited Edition.  I want to sign the resulting msi package.  I realize that you can purchase a certificate from VeriSign or elsewhere.  Is it possible to generate my own certificate and sign the package?

As further clarification, the installer will be used by internal IT staff and not distributed to the public, so I don't need to worry about the trust level of self-signing.

Answer (score 0):

Any valid cert can be used by InstallShield.  However your IT department probably has a certificate enrollment process so they can generate one for you that's trusted by their organization.